# How to hide jquery datatable Rows with conditions in ASP.Net MVC5?

Tags: jquery, .net, datatables

Work on Asp.net mvc5.In my project view jquery datatable, want to dynamically hide rows with condition,after hide row how to retrieve this hidden rows values.

**Is it possible in Jquery Datatable?**

**Note:** [this](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html) link shows me how to work with column not get yet how to work with rows

Comment: Can you use the search functionality? That would only show the rows you want, right?

Comment: @ Mario Lopez,Thank for your reply,will you please show me some syntax how to hide/filter selected row base on button click event condition

Comment: I was talking about the search input that datatables has by default. I'm probably not getting what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to have buttons to hide rows? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your table definition `.dataTable({ ... })` you have to add something like the following

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    if (aData.ToHide == true) {
        var row = $('td', nRow).closest('tr');
        row.data("storeSomeDataToDistinguishTheRowCanBeAnId", 12343);
        row.hide();
    }

    return nRow;
}
```

Now depends on your implementation but a suggestion is to store some jQuery `data` in order to distinguish if you have to show the row or not. After that you just use jQuery selectors to find the row by the `data` you previously stored.

The above applies when you load the data using `.dataTable({ ... })` plugin.

For just in case (i don't know your implementation) i also recommend you to load the data asynchronously using `Ajax`. That permits less processing time by the server, the page loads faster and then `dataTable` queries the data asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

There is an example on the official documentation about [Search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()):

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();

 // #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
 $('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
 } );
```

You can try to have your buttons like:

```
<input id="#myInput" value="foo">Show only Foo values</input>
```